# Is the verb 'will' modal in these sentences?

Tags: modal-verbs, will-would-meaning-wanting-to

- Everyone will get it: Virus warning.
- Virus will ‘get worse, very quickly’.

Answer (score 1):

*Will* is always modal, except for the (now rare) use in the sense of "wish so strongly that it happens".

A very common meaning of the modal is expectation, i.e. future time.

Comment: That's a modal, too; it's the deontic sense of _If he will agree, we can all settle this_, meaning if he's willing to agree. The syntax is strongly influenced by magic, of course, but there was magic in those days, just the same way there's news today -- something everybody believes in gets talked about.

Comment: I meant the non-modal use as in "God had willed it to be so". Perhaps I should have given an example.

Comment: God is the only one who can cause things to happen by wanting them. Deus le volt. Others can only dream of a causative _want_.

Comment: That's philosophy not linguistics. Among the first few hits on "willed" in the NOW corpus are "as she willed her way through an 85-minute marathon"; "while they willed their side to find a way to defeat Wolves"; "not willed by the people at elections, but forced by an economy in the doldrums"; " abortion willed either as an end or a means".

Comment: _Will one's way_ seems to be a  metaphoric motion verb; and the rest are all just _want_, with, granted, somewhat different syntax. The deontic sense of _will_ is, after all, _want_, just like German, but again with different syntax. The fact that _will_ mostly gets used in the epistemic sense tends to blind us.